# --git-dir changes directory in .bashrc in WSL

Tags: bash, git, directory

I created a script that prints out all my git repo libraries with the current branch names. But for some reason, it changes the current directory at the end.

I have a ".bash_aliases" script that I call from .bashrc, so:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
. ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

The .bash_aliases file contains some aliases and variables, such as these:

```
repo1Dir=~/repo1/
repo2Dir=~/repo2/
repo3Dir=~/repo3/
alias repo1="cd $repo1Dir"
alias repo2="cd $repo2Dir"
alias repo3="cd $repo3Dir"
```

And I added this script at the end of the file:

```
echo -n "repo1 -> "
git --git-dir $repo1Dir".git" --work-tree=$repo1Dir rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
echo -n "repo2 -> "
git --git-dir $repo2Dir".git" --work-tree=$repo2Dir rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
echo -n "repo3 -> "
git --git-dir $repo3Dir".git" --work-tree=$repo3Dir rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

When I start a WSL terminal, it will print this at initialization:

```
repo1 -> branch_abc
repo2 -> branch_cba
repo3 -> main
```

I expect that the current folder will end up being HOME because I didn't change that before and as far as I know the command `--git-dir` doesn't change the current dir. But in the end, the current folder will be this one:

```
myComputer@DESKTOP-PC:~/repo3$
```

So the folder of the last command. If I type one of these git commands in the terminal, the current folder will not change.

This becomes a problem if I want to work with repo2 for example. I type this:

```
repo2
```

and the current folder will be this of course: `myComputer@DESKTOP-PC:~/repo2$`. Then I start vscode with the `code .` command. The vscode opens repo2. The vscode's terminal will of course print the branches (which are in .bash_aliases) and then this will be the current directory: `myComputer@DESKTOP-PC:~/repo3$`

Why does it change the directory and how can I prevent it?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Your diagnosis is wrong: `git --git-dir=...` does not *change* the current working directory, it merely sets a temporary environment variable for the duration of the particular Git operation. Some *other* action in your setup is moving you to the `repo3` directory. Note that IDEs generally start up once and then *keep running*, and when you do operations in shell windows, that does not start a new instance of the IDE, it merely delivers a request to the running IDE (which is still in whatever directory it's in).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @torek ! Now I use another approach.